# Quick Change Profiles App

Tags: profiles

I used to use an app called quick profiles on my old phone, but can't find this or anything similar on the play store for my new phone.
I used it to switch between different profiles for night home and work. It would change the screen brightness, volume, and vibrate setting for each profile.

Anyone know of something similar that's still available today?

Comment: Sounds similar to my old One Plus phone which had [such customization](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/95124/3573). Sadly on my non-rooted stock Google Pixel 2 phone the closest is 'Digital Wellbeing'.